# Unable to submit multiple records into the same database using one form

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have a form, populated with data from the database, with a radio list button in each record. After ticking and submitting the form, only the last record is saved to the database, but I want all records to be saved.
Here is my code:
//the form code fetching/querying the database

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'class')->label('Class')->dropDownList(
            Arrayhelper::map(Classes::find()->all(), 'class_name', 
     'class_name'),
            [
                'maxlength' => true,
                'style'=>'width: 300px; height: 50px;',
                'prompt'=>'select class',
                'onchange'=>'
                    $.post( "index.php?
   r=attendance/list&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                    $("section#Attend").html(data);
                    });'
                ]); ?>
```

//the controller code fetching and sending the result to the form

```
   public function actionList($id){
        $model = new Attendance;
        $form = new ActiveForm;

        $countclass = Registrationinfo::find()
                ->where(['current_class' => $id])
                ->count();
        $lga = Registrationinfo::find()
                ->where(['current_class' => $id])
                ->all();
        if($countclass > 0){
            foreach($lga as $data){ ?>
              <div >
            <div class="col-md-1"><?= ('1')?></div>
            <div style="display: inline;"><?= $data['first_name'] ?></div>
            <div style="display: inline; margin-left: 20px;"><?= 
$data['surname'] ?></div>
            <div style="display: inline; margin-left: 79px;"><?= 
  $data['gender'] ?></div>
            <div style="display: inline; margin-left: 20px;"><?= $form-
  >field($model, 'student_id')->textInput(['value'=>$data->reg_no, 
  'disabled'=>''])->label(false) ?></div>
            <div style="display: inline; margin-left: 150px;"> <?= $form-
  >field($model, 'status')
     ->radioList(array('PR' => 'Present', 'PM' =>'Permission', 'LT' 
   =>'Late', 'AB' =>'Absent'), array('class' => 'i-checks')); ?>
                <hr style="color: blue;">
        <?php
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<div class=>'info'>Invalide Class name </div>";
        }
    }
```

//my actionCreate from the same controller

```
   public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = [new Attendance()];
        //select date from datesetup where status is open
        $date = DateSetup::findbysql('SELECT date from date_setup WHERE 
   status = "open"')->all();
        if(count($date) > 0){
            foreach ($date as $dates);
        }else{
            echo "No date As been opened yet";
        }
        //select Term from Termsetup where status is open
        $terms = Termsetup::findbysql('SELECT term from termsetup WHERE 
    status = "open"')->all();
        if(count($terms) > 0){
            foreach ($terms as $term);
        }else{
            echo "No Term As been opened yet";
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) 
     {
     //adding the database value retrive to the attandance form field    
            $model->term = $term->term;
            $model->day = date('d', strtotime('$dates'));
            $model->month = date('m', strtotime('$dates'));
            $model->year = date('Y', strtotime('$dates'));
            $model->date = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
            $model->user_id = "admin";
            if ( isset( $_POST['student_id'] ) ) {
    $model->student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    // validate, save or more..
    }
     else {
      echo "reg_no not posted"; //return array
     }
            //$model->student_id = $data->student_id;
            //$model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id;
            if($model->save())

       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        return $this->render('create', [
           'model' => $model,
            ]);
     }
```

Comment: You need to start doing some debugging yourself, we're not gonna read through all this code to figure out what isn't working for you. Turn on error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: the issue is that after ticking the first radio button, when i tick the second one (in the next record), the first button automatically uncheck itself @Epodax

Answer (score 0):

Declare your name attribute of the forms as array, for update / insert go over the every element of the form (use for each) and run insert / update statement for every element.

Comment: am kind of new to yii frame work, and might be having a little difficulty on where/ how to declare it @S.Kartik

Comment: Sample code:                                                                                       
 <input type="text" name="hours[]"  value="<?php echo $hour_entered ?>" style="text-align:center" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>                                                                                 foreach ($hours as $key => $value) {
    # code...

    // echo $value."--".$date[$key]."\n";

    $enter_date = $date[$key];

    // $sql_statement=